# Jython can import lib when run in a single myapp-with-dependencies.jar but not when jython is separate

Tags: classpath, jython

I have an application which consists of some Java classes and some Python scripts; I use Jython from my Java code to invoke the Python scripts.

My application is built using Maven, and produces an ordinary `.jar` file containing the compiled Java classes, and the Python scripts as resources. I also use `maven-assembly-plugin` to generate a `myapp-with-dependencies.jar` that contains the same plus bundles in the contents of the Jython dependencies.

When I run my application using the with-dependencies jar:

```
java -classpath target/myapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.example.myapp.Main
```

...it works as expected. But when I run it using two separate jars:

```
java -classpath "target/myapp-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/Users/richard/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.5.3/jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar" com.example.myapp.Main
```

...it fails: when I ask Jython to execute "import mylib" I get an exception:

```
ImportError: No module named mylib
```

In both cases, the exact contents of the classpath should be completely identical, the only difference is that in the first case everything is in one jar, but in the second case it is split across two jars.

What could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Exactly where is `mylib` in each of the two scenarios?

Comment: @DavidCharles source is in `src/main/resources/Lib/mylib` (directory contains `__init__.py` and other py scripts); Maven puts these in `Lib/mylib/*.py` in both of the `myapp-*.jar` files